# what is the meaning of "n/n/n" in the header of csv file? how can I make a data frame from this file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import-csv

[Dataframe after importing csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZjR.jpg)

> [Kunde;Produkt;Kampagne;Vermarkter/Verlag;Werbeträger;Datum von;Datum bis;Platzierung;Werbeform;Menge;Einheit;**n/n/n**;Tracking-ID;AdGap-ID]

I am trying to expand this data to a pandas data frame, but I am confused about this header. After importing this *.csv file into my python data frame there are two columns.

So far I have made two data frame, using the first column and second column. But how I can combine them? what is the relation between this two data frames?

[Data frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRj8i.jpg)

[Data frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI4rE.jpg)

Comment: It has no meaning. The header of a csv file is the first line and it is comma sparated in exactly the same way as the data in the subsequent lines below.

Comment: In the first line columns are=  
['Kunde', 'Produkt', 'Kampagne', 'Vermarkter/Verlag', 'Werbeträger', 'Datum von', 'Datum bis', 'Platzierung', 'Werbeform', 'Menge', 'Einheit', 'n/n/n', 'Tracking-ID', 'AdGap-ID,'] which makes 14 columns 

but there are 11 values just below this column, and 3 values in unnamed: 1

my question is what is the relation between first column and Unnamed: 1

Comment: it looks like the creator od the csv file wanted to make new lines `\n` and somehow they went into a header. The csv file is malformed. Your code is probably correct.

Comment: What happens when you use `;` as the delimiter? e.g. `read_csv(xxxx, sep=';')`

Comment: it gives a dataframe with an extra column "n/n/n" there are some number in that column with a comma(,) in that number . So i am using all the other columns except that column.